# SELinux silently blocking PHP process listing

Tags: php, php-fpm, selinux, auditd

I have a system where we use PHP to run some rudimentary health checks on the server.  When hitting a status page, it verifies that certain processes are running, and returns an error message if something is failing.

When we set this up with RHEL 7, we observed that running shell_exec("ps -ax") would only return processes executed by the PHP user, so it could not "see" whether the specific server processes were running.  And after some investigation we found that this was a restriction enforced by selinux.  We could see the denies in auditd.log, and ultimately got it working with this selinux policy module:

```
require {
    type httpd_t;
    type initrc_t;
    class dir getattr;
    class dir search;
    class file read;
    class file open;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t initrc_t:dir getattr;
allow httpd_t initrc_t:dir search;
allow httpd_t initrc_t:file read;
allow httpd_t initrc_t:file open;
```

We're re-building this server on RHEL 8 now, but the same policy does not work.  The same situation I described earlier is happening - shell_exec(ps -ax) only returns processes from the running user.  However, when checking the audit log on RHEL 8 we see no denies being logged at all for php.  I disabled and removed the above policy module, but still see nothing getting denied.

If I run "setenforce Permissive" then re-run my test, PHP can then see all running processes.  Running "setenforce Enforcing" restores the original behavior, so it's clear that selinux is preventing this, but without any logging I don't know how to *fix* it.

Does anyone know how to force SELinux to log why it's denying this?  I see it logging other denies, so I don't know why this is excluded.  I tried running the following:

```
auditctl -w /usr/sbin/php-fpm
auditctl -w /usr/bin/ps
```

And now I can see that ps is being *run* in audit.log, but still nothing about what's being denied.

I'm not terribly familiar with selinux and I'm grasping at straws at this point.  How can I find out what specifically is being denied?

Comment: You should start by returning the output of `ausearch -ts today -m avc,user_avc,user_role_change` and seeing what outputs (assuming you've had this alert today)

Comment: Hi, @MatthewIfe.  That didn't seem to make any difference looking for denies, but shortly after posting this I found https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Logging, which explains that <code>semodule -DB</code> can be used to disable "cosmetic" logs from being ignored, which in this case was critical for what I needed.  That ultimately gave me the info I need to write a new policy module.